# How to use MutationObserver to listen the video load event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In my expectation, I wish to use MutationObserver to listen to the event that tells the video has loaded. The reason for that is I need to add a loading animation before the video has been rendered and loaded in the DOM, then remove the animation when the video showed on the page.  It seems that MutationObserver couldn't tell the time when the video loaded, it only knows the attributes changed.
 Below is my code:

```
const callback =  () => {
  console.log('done')
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback)
this.observer.observe(videoNode, {
  attributes: true
})
```

Comment: You're mistaken: `MutationObserver` won't work for this because the DOM tree doesn't mutate when a video loads. Why aren't you using the `load` event on the `HTMLVideoElement` instead?

Answer (score 1):

> In my expectation, I wish to use `MutationObserver` to listen to the event that tells the video has loaded. The reason for that is I need to add a loading animation before the video has been rendered and loaded in the DOM, then remove the animation when the video showed on the page. It seems that `MutationObserver` couldn't tell the time when the video loaded, it only knows the attributes changed. below is my code.

Why are you `MutationObserver` for this when `HTMLVideoElement` already has a `load` event and and `readyState` properties that tell you this exact information? (Though you probably should use the `canplay` or the `loadeddata` events instead of `load`).

Using `MutationObserver` won't work anyway because it's for observing structural changes to the DOM tree (e.g. adding/removing elements and attributes, but *not* object properties), so it won't observe changes to DOM properties that are independent of DOM attributes (as element attributes do not map 1:1 to object properties, this also applies to CSS: you can set `disabled` on `HTMLInputElement` and the `:disabled` psuedo-class will work, but it won't match the `[disabled]` attribute selector).

All you need is this:

```
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState
const READYSTATE_HAVE_NOTHING      = 0;
const READYSTATE_HAVE_METADATA     = 1;
const READYSTATE_HAVE_CURRENT_DATA = 2;
const READYSTATE_HAVE_FUTURE_DATA  = 3;
const READYSTATE_HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA  = 4;

const videoElement = document.querySelector( 'video#someId' );
if( !videoElement ) throw new Error( "Couldn't find <video> element." );


if( videoElement.readyState === READYSTATE_HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA ) {
    // If the video is already loaded, don't do anything.
}
else {
    // Else, show the spinner and remove it after it's loaded:
    const spinner = document.createElement('div');
    spinner.classList.add('spinner');
    videoElement.parent.appendChild( spinner );

    videoElement.addEventListener( 'canplay', function() {
        document.querySelector('.spinner')?.remove();
    } );
}
```

Comment: Hi Dai, Thanks for the answer ! I use the HTMLVideoElement load event to fix this eventually,  You are right MutationOberser couldn't deal with this case. I'm glad to learn more information from you about the MutationObserver!